# How is crond daemon started without an init.d/chkconfig entry?

Tags: cron

I'm running a sandbox server with Fedora 15. I've gathered that since my crontab file has no entries (ie. `***** run-parts /dir/`) for scheduled run-parts, it is not currently configured. The `ps` command reveals its running with the -n option. Where is this option set? Is the sysconfig the only place crond options are editable?

All of the documentation I've discovered discusses the run-parts entries in detail; however, none discuss crond options. What I have found references `init.d/crond`, which I don't have in this installation. If chkconfig is not controlling the startup of crond, what is?

---

What I'm working on doing is turning on anacron. 
According to what I've discovered about anacron from random [anacron set-up](http://www.it.uc3m.es/marcos/doc/miniHOWTOs/miniHOWTO-Use_anacron_as_non-root_user.html) [tutorials](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/05/anacron-examples/), I first need to have cron running hourly to trigger the anacron script which then handles the daily plus jobs. Okay.

Once I get all these cron jobs running these installed cron jobs, which are not currently being executed, are all going to start running and bogging up my system with mail alerts. I want to set crond with the -m option. And before I just add options to `sysconfig/crond`, I want to understand where is this current option -n being set.

Comment: do you have a ~/xinitrc file?

Comment: Nope. I found the answer and have posted it below.

Answer (score 1):

After some checking at other sources, I've discovered Fedora has changed to something called [`systemd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd), according to Wikipedia, in 2010. (I kinda recall this now--I guess I just forget all the under the hood config stuff after each major upgrade :-). Armed with this term, I was able to find [some](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd) [useful](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SysVinit_to_Systemd_Cheatsheet) [information](http://sys-log.bencane.com/2012/01/cheat-sheet-systemctl-vs-chkconfig/).